# query to display four random data from database with out repeating

Tags: php, html, mysql

i'm trying to display quotes but i can't seem to get the data to show on the index page i'm still new to php and mysql and its been a ruff road

html index page

```
<div class="quote">
  <div class="container">

    <blockquote class="blockquote">
      <p class="mb-0">"<?php echo $row['feedback']; ?>"</p>
      <footer class="blockquote-footer"><?php echo $row['companyname']; ?></footer>
    </blockquote>

    <blockquote class="blockquote-reverse">
      <p class="mb-0">"<?php echo $row['feedback']; ?>"</p>
      <footer class="blockquote-footer"><?php echo $row['companyname']; ?></footer>
    </blockquote>

    <blockquote class="blockquote">
      <p class="mb-0">"<?php echo $row['feedback']; ?>"</p>
      <footer class="blockquote-footer"><?php echo $row['companyname']; ?></footer>
    </blockquote>

  </div>
</div>
```

and database connect

```
<?php
$hostname = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$db = "";

$dbconnect=mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$db);

if ($dbconnect->connect_error) {
  die("Database connection failed: " . $dbconnect->connect_error);
}
$query="SELECT companyname,feedback,status from review WHERE status=? ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3";
?>
```

Comment: Think you just forgot to execute your query. Where is the `mysqli_query` call ?

Comment: it didn't post and i dont know why

Comment: Hey you may want to look into prepared statements. Its just some advice that I received when I first started using PHP. But as for your question I would take a look at this post on the MySQL RAND function, it will help you out http://www.mysqltutorial.org/select-random-records-database-table.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <?php
    $hostname = "";
    $username = "";
    $password = "";
    $db = "";

    $dbconnect=mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$db);

    if ($dbconnect->connect_error) {
      die("Database connection failed: " . $dbconnect->connect_error);
    }
    $query=mysqli_query($dbconnect,"SELECT companyname,feedback,status from review WHERE status=? ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3");

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    ?>
```

Comment: i'm still getting an issue with is not showing on the it just shows up blank https://gyazo.com/0cc8ba8c86829244e38b7d3bb31d6d16

Comment: Check your variables in index page. You should use $row[''].

Comment: same results nothing showing up i updated all the variables and still coming up empty

Comment: Ok i fixed it but now its just displaying the same record on every line

Comment: You have to use while loop